# How to overwrite a block with an included file

Tags: twig

i would like to override/extend a block from the layout.twig from an included twig file.

How can I achieve this?

The reason for this is that I have outsourced some elements into different twig files in order to be able to use them over and over again.
These twig files should be expanded in layout.twig.

I tried different solutions:

The embed tag only overwrites blocks within the included file.

The use tag does not allow the parent block to be extended in layout.twig.

Also [https://github.com/rybakit/twig-deferred-extension] did not have the desired effect.

**layout.twig**

```
<div style="color:red;">
{% block content %}
    <h1>content: layout</h1>
{% endblock %}
</div>

<div style="color:blue;">
{% block morecontent %}
    <h1>morecontent: layout</h1>
{% endblock %}
</div>
```

**content.twig**

```
{% extends "layout.twig" %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>content: content</h1>

    {% include "include.twig" %}
    {% include "include2.twig" %}
{% endblock %}
```

**include.twig**

```
<h1>content: include</h1>

{% block morecontent %}
    <h1>morecontent: include</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

**include2.twig**

```
<h1>content: include2</h1>

{% block morecontent %}
    <h1>morecontent: include2</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

This way, the "morecontent" of the included files will be put directly after the content.

```
<div style="color:red;">
    <h1>content: content</h1>
    <h1>content: include</h1>
    <h1>morecontent: include</h1>
    <h1>content: include2</h1>
    <h1>morecontent: include2</h1>
</div>
<div style="color:blue;">
    <h1>morecontent: layout</h1>
</div>
```

But I want them to be inside the morecontent Block of the layout.twig

```
 <div style="color:red;">
    <h1>content: content</h1>
    <h1>content: include</h1>
    <h1>content: include2</h1>
</div>
<div style="color:blue;">
    <h1>morecontent: layout</h1>
    <h1>morecontent: include</h1>
    <h1>morecontent: include2</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: How did you use the defered extension in here? I'd suggest to fill an array with the includes you want to display in the block and then loop the includes

Comment: Hi, I used it in the {% block morecontent deferred %} in the layout.twig. Thanks for your hint to fill it to the array. That helps! By defining a global variable where I append the html and loop it in the layout.twig!

Comment: Your welcome :) Shame this is still not a feature in `twig` though